# Ansible Unable to Perform 'Yum Install' task on Single Server (out of many)

Tags: python, ansible

My Ansible Info

- ansible 2.8.2
- python 2.7.5

My Issue

I'm running my ansible-playbook on my hosts. All hosts were able to perform the yum install except one. When I run the ansible-playbook and found out one host wasn't performing the ansible task, I ran my ansible-playbook in debug mode (using -vvvv). You can see my error below.

I'm assuming this issue has to do with a plugin (for ansible, yum, or maybe with repoquery directly). But I've performed a `yum install yum-utils` and `yum install rhn-plugin`, both are installed and are the latest version.

ERROR

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_yum_payload_Xfj0RP/ansible_yum_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2561, in run_command
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/bin/repoquery --show-duplicates --plugins --quiet --disablerepo '' --enablerepo myrepo --qf '%{epoch}:%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}' --whatprovides my-custom-rpm", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_downgrade": false, 
            "autoremove": false, 
            "bugfix": false, 
            "conf_file": null, 
            "disable_excludes": null, 
            "disable_gpg_check": true, 
            "disable_plugin": [], 
            "disablerepo": [], 
            "download_dir": null, 
            "download_only": false, 
            "enable_plugin": [], 
            "enablerepo": [
                "myrepo"
            ], 
            "exclude": [], 
            "install_repoquery": true, 
            "install_weak_deps": true, 
            "installroot": "/", 
            "list": null, 
            "lock_timeout": 0, 
            "name": [
                "my-custom-rpm"
            ], 
            "releasever": null, 
            "security": false, 
            "skip_broken": false, 
            "state": "latest", 
            "update_cache": false, 
            "update_only": false, 
            "use_backend": "auto", 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "[Errno 8] Exec format error", 
    "rc": 8
}
```

---

Running `rpm --verify yum-utils` outputs the following:

```
S.5......    /etc/bash_completion.d/yum-utils.bash
S.5......    /usr/bin/debuginfo-install
S.5......    /usr/bin/find-repos-of-install
S.5......    /usr/bin/needs-restarting
S.5......    /usr/bin/package-cleanup
S.5......    /usr/bin/repo-graph
S.5......    /usr/bin/repo-rss
S.5......    /usr/bin/repoclosure
S.5......    /usr/bin/repodiff
S.5......    /usr/bin/repomanage
S.5......    /usr/bin/repoquery
S.5......    /usr/bin/reposync
S.5......    /usr/bin/repotrack
S.5......    /usr/bin/show-changed-rco
S.5......    /usr/bin/show-installed
S.5......    /usr/bin/verifytree
S.5......    /usr/bin/yum-builddep
S.5......    /usr/bin/yum-config-manager
S.5......    /usr/bin/yum-debug-dump
S.5......    /usr/bin/yum-debug-restore
S.5......    /usr/bin/yum-groups-manager
S.5......    /usr/bin/yumdownloader
S.5......  d /usr/share/doc/yum-utils-1.1.31/COPYING
S.5......  d /usr/share/doc/yum-utils-1.1.31/README
S.5......  d /usr/share/doc/yum-utils-1.1.31/yum-util-cli-template
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/debuginfo-install.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/find-repos-of-install.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/needs-restarting.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/package-cleanup.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repo-graph.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repo-rss.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repoclosure.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repodiff.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repomanage.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repoquery.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/reposync.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/repotrack.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/show-changed-rco.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/show-installed.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/verifytree.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yum-builddep.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yum-config-manager.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yum-debug-dump.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yum-debug-restore.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yum-groups-manager.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yum-utils.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man1/yumdownloader.1.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man8/yum-complete-transaction.8.gz
S.5......  d /usr/share/man/man8/yumdb.8.gz
```

Comment: You're getting an "exec format error". Are you able to run `/bin/repoquery` on that server by hand? What happens?

Comment: Interesting, no I can't seem to get it to work. After executing the command, nothing returns. I can't seem to get anything to output. Is there a command I can run that can confirm this issue? As I mentioned in my post, I already checked to see if I have the latest install of ```yum-utils``` and it says I currently have version 1.1.31-50.el7.noarch

Comment: The "exec format error" usually means "you're trying to run something that is executable but isn't a binary format that can run on this platform".  `repoquery` is a Python script so this doesn't necessarily make sense. What does `file /bin/repoquery` report? How about `rpm --verify yum-utils` (which ideally should produce no output)?

Comment: Running ```file /bin/repoquery``` outputs: /bin/repoquery: empty
Running ```rpm --verify yum-utils``` has a lot of stuff in the output. See my post, below ERROR section.

Answer (score 1):

Something is terribly wrong with your system.

Your immediate problem is that `/bin/repoquery` seems to be empty. But beyond that, the output of `rpm --verify` indicates that just about every file in the `yum-utils` package has been modified.

First, check if there your filesystem has run out of space.

You can try re-installing the `yum-utils` package, but honestly, this degree of problem suggests that there are probably a variety of other things on your system that are broken. Your best bet would be to wipe it and re-install from scratch.